# I dont see admin thumbs in custom posts list

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a wordpress photo gallery using custom post types.

```
$gallery_labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type general name', 'test' ),
    'singular_name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type singular name', 'test' ),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'gallery', 'test' ),
    'add_new_item' => __("Add New Gallery", 'test' ),
    'edit_item' => __("Edit Gallery", 'test' ),
    'new_item' => __("New Gallery", 'test' ),
    'view_item' => __("View Gallery"),
    'search_items' => __("Search Gallery", 'test' ),
    'not_found' =>  __('No galleries found', 'test' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No galleries found in Trash', 'test' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''

);
$gallery_args = array(
    'labels' => $gallery_labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category'),
    'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','thumbnail','comments','excerpt','page-attributes'),
    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/photo-album.png' //16x16 png if you want an icon
);
register_post_type('gallery', $gallery_args);
//----------------------------------------------
//------------------------create custom taxonomy
//----------------------------------------------
add_action( 'init', 'jss_create_gallery_taxonomies', 0);

function jss_create_gallery_taxonomies(){
    register_taxonomy(
        'phototype', 'gallery',
        array(
            'hierarchical'=> true,
            'label' => 'Photo Categories',
            'singular_label' => 'Category',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true
        )
    );    
}

 //----------------------------------------------
        //--------------------------admin custom columns
        //----------------------------------------------
        //admin_init
        add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'jss_custom_columns');
        add_filter('manage_edit-gallery_columns', 'jss_add_new_gallery_columns');

        function jss_add_new_gallery_columns( $columns ){
            $columns = array(
                'cb'                =>        '<input type="checkbox">',
                'jss_post_thumb'    =>        'Thumbnail',
                'title'             =>        'Album Title',
                'phototype'         =>        'Category',
                'author'            =>        'Author',
                'date'              =>        'Date'

            );
            return $columns;
        }

        function jss_custom_columns( $column ){
            global $post;

            switch ($column) {
                case 'jss_post_thumb' : echo the_post_thumbnail('admin-list-thumb'); break;
                case 'description' : the_excerpt(); break;
                case 'phototype' : echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'gallery', '', ', ',''); break;
            }
        }

        //add thumbnail images to column
        add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'jss_add_post_thumbnail_column', 5);
        add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'jss_add_post_thumbnail_column', 5);
        add_filter('manage_custom_post_columns', 'jss_add_post_thumbnail_column', 5);
        // Add the column
        function jss_add_post_thumbnail_column($cols){
            $cols['jss_post_thumb'] = __('Thumbnail');
            return $cols;
        }

        function jss_display_post_thumbnail_column($col, $id){
          switch($col){
            case 'jss_post_thumb':
              if( function_exists('the_post_thumbnail') )
                echo the_post_thumbnail( 'admin-list-thumb' );
              else
                echo 'Not supported in this theme';
              break;
          }
        }
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );
        function myajax_submit() {
        // get the submitted parameters
           $postID = $_POST['postID'];

           $response = get_thumbnail_images(); 
           $response = json_encode($response);

        // response output
           header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
           echo $response;

        // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
        exit;
        }
        //----------------------------------------------
        //--------------add theme support for thumbnails
        //----------------------------------------------

        add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_getarchives_where' );
        function custom_getarchives_where( $where ){
            $where = str_replace( "post_type = 'post'", "post_type IN ( 'post', 'gallery' )", $where );
            return $where;
        }
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_podcasts_to_archive' );
        function add_podcasts_to_archive( $query ) {
          if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive() && !is_admin() )
             $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'gallery' ) );
          return $query;
        }

        function wp_list_categories_for_post_type($post_type, $args = '') {
            $exclude = array();

            // Check ALL categories for posts of given post type
            foreach (get_categories() as $category) {
                $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => $post_type, 'category' => $category->cat_ID));

                // If no posts found, ...
                if (empty($posts))
                    // ...add category to exclude list
                    $exclude[] = $category->cat_ID;
            }

            // Set up args
            if (! empty($exclude)) {
                $args .= ('' === $args) ? '' : '&';
                $args .= 'exclude='.implode(',', $exclude);
            }

            // List categories
            wp_list_categories($args);
        }
```

working nice on front end but in admin I dont see the thumbnails and categories

Here is a screenshot http://s12.postimg.org/mqtkb274t/gallery.png what Im talking about

I dont understand where can be the problem I also added thumbnail support for admin 80 x 80 but not on this code

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen--wp-24934

Comment: the tutorials I know as you see I have all in my codes but I wanted to know only where I'm wrong any way thanks for the link but I did all

Comment: See `add_filter` after `//admin_init` and `//add thumbnail images to column. `manage_posts_custom_column` use for default post type not custom post type.Here you create `gallery` post type.so read below link and implement.

Comment: thanks himansu! as first link you gave helped me to get thumbnails I changed the codes wich you said and to get categories I was wrong here   `case 'phototype' : echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'gallery', '', ', ',''); break;`  so changed the `galler`y to `phototype` and everything worked fine thanks again..